# Vue JS Custom directive data binding

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm creating a custom directive to make a form submit via ajax - however I can't seem to get validation errors to bind to the Vue instance.

I am adding my directive here:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.settings.update.security', [$user->uuid]) }}" method="POST"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data" v-ajax errors="formErrors.security" data="formData.security">
```

My directive looks like:

```
Vue.directive('ajax', {
        twoWay: true,
        params: ['errors', 'data'],

        bind: function () {
            this.el.addEventListener('submit', this.onSubmit.bind(this));
        },

        update: function (value) {

        },

        onSubmit: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            this.vm
                    .$http[this.getRequestType()](this.el.action, vm[this.params.data])
                    .then(this.onComplete.bind(this))
                    .catch(this.onError.bind(this));
        },

        onComplete: function () {
            swal({
                title: 'Success!',
                text: this.params.success,
                type: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: 'Back'
            });

        },

        onError: function (response) {
            swal({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: response.data.message,
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Back'
            });

            this.set(this.vm, this.params.errors, response.data);
        },

        getRequestType: function () {
            var method = this.el.querySelector('input[name="_method"]');

            return (method ? method.value : this.el.method).toLowerCase();
        },
    });
```

And my VUE instance looks like:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#settings',

        data: function () {
            return {
                active: 'profile',
                updatedSettings: getSharedData('updated'),
                formData: {
                    security: {
                        current_password: ''
                    }
                },
                formErrors: {
                    security: []
                },
            }
        },

        methods: {
            setActive: function (name) {
                this.active = name;
            },

            isActive: function (name) {
                if (this.active == name) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },

            hasError: function (item, array, sub) {
                if (this[array][sub][item]) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },

            isInArray: function (value, array) {
                return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
            },

            showNotification: function () {
                if (this.updatedSettings) {
                    $.iGrowl({
                        title: 'Updated',
                        message: 'Your settings have been updated successfully.',
                        type: 'success',
                    });
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

However, when I output the data, the value for formErrors.security is empty

Any idea why?

Comment: It seems like you are missing the `:` in front of the props: `<form action="{{ route('user.settings.update.security', [$user->uuid]) }}" method="POST"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data" v-ajax :errors="formErrors.security" :data="formData.security">`

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it, still nothing is getting saved :/

Comment: Where do you add anything to `formErrors`, as far as I see, you never update `formErrors`

Comment: I'm doing it dynamically. I'm getting what to add from the `errors` parameter on the form. I'm then setting it using `this.set(this.vm, this.params.errors, response.data);` on the directive

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `this.set(/* ... */)` line. `this.set` doesn't work the same as `Vue.set` or `vm.$set`.

`this.set` attempts to set the path that you passed to the directive: `v-my-directive="a.b.c"`. So running `this.set('foo')` will attempt to set `$vm.a.b.c` to `'foo'`.

What you want to do is this:

(ES6)

```
this.params.errors.splice(0, this.params.errors.length, ...response.data)
```

(Vanilla JS)

```
this.params.errors.splice.apply(this.params.errors, [0,this.params.errors.length].concat(response.data))
```

That will update whatever Object is tied to the `errors` param on the DOM Node. Make sure that you do `v-bind:errors="formErrors.security"` or `:errors="formErrors.security"`.